# Set alert in chosen jQuery plugin

Tags: html, jquery, if-statement, alert, jquery-chosen

I am using jQuery chosen plugin to set status of a product. So I wanted to set an alert. Means when I set disabled option and click Add Item an alert() will show on top.[Image of sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ZKZ.png). I am not understanding what should I write in my if() condition. Here is my code where I sticked.

```
//Check status if user selected disabled option
        if($status == 'disabled'){
            alert("you select disabled Item");
                exit();
        }
```

I am not getting if my condition is right/wrong, cause this condition is not working. Please help

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
// Style the dropdown boxes. You need to explicitly set the width 
// in order to fix the dropdown box not visible issue when tab is hidden
$('.chosenSelect').chosen({ width: "95%"});
}
```

Code of script for working with chosen plugin

Comment: What's the value of `$status`?  How are you getting this value?

Comment: What are the values in the `select`? For example, you compare as `disabled` but your image shows `Disabled` - so it might just be a case of converting $status to lower case or comparing `if ($status === 'Disabled')`

Comment: $status = htmlentities($_POST['itemDetailsStatus']); This is the value of $status, itemDetailsStatus is the name of the select button @freedomn-m

Comment: I have 2 values for select. one is active and another one is disabled. so I want to show an alert when I select disabled and click Add Item Button...

Comment: `$status = htmlentities($_POST['itemDetailsStatus'])` is [tag:php] *not* [tag:javascript] - so it won't ever be "what the user selected".  Please provided a *complete* [mcve] *in html and javascript/jquery* (no php as your question is about [tag:jquery-chosen])

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value on the button trigger like this

```
$('#updateItemDetailsButton').on('click', function(){
  if ($('.chosenSelect option:selected').val() == 'disabled') {
    alert("you select disabled Item");
  } else {
    updateItem();
  }
});
```

or you can check for events triggered when the dropdown is changed like this

```
$('.chosenSelect').on('change', function(evt, params) {
   if (params && params.selected == 'disabled') {
     alert("you select disabled Item");
   } else {
     alert("no option selected");
   }
});
```

For more info:
https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events

Comment: when I am pushing these code in my code, my  Button is not Add Item button is not working. I am not sure where to paste this code in my html code section or in script?...

Comment: Please provide your button js code

Comment: // Listen to update button in item details tab
 $('#updateItemDetailsButton').on('click', function(){
  updateItem();
 });   //updateItem function code
function updateItem() {
var itemDetailsStatus = $('#itemDetailsStatus').val();
$.ajax({
  url: 'model/item/updateItemDetails.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
  itemDetailsStatus:itemDetailsStatus,
 },
 success: function(data){
   var result = $.parseJSON(data);
   $('#itemDetailsMessage').fadeIn();
   $('#itemDetailsMessage').html(result.alertMessage);
   } }, }); }

Comment: I have updated the code please review.

Comment: shall I put the condition in script page or in html page? @Darshan Gada